# How to find bugs in new JavaFx bug tracker

Tags: javafx, bug-tracker

Existing links to javafx bugs are dead. How can I find bugs in new system? E.g. how to find bug
https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28874
in
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net

Comment: Looks like `openjdk.java.net` is under maintenance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated on "https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/"

> The JavaFX bugs are now on bugs.openjdk.java.net, go there and search for the ID RT-____ to find the bug you are looking for.

After using the search for your ID, I landed here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090548

;) seems pretty easy (checked the correct mapping with some bug-id I found myself, seems to work)

Comment: Simple indeed, but it certainly wasn't working for quite a long time

Comment: Yes, I struggled over that problem myself :D but time cures wounds ;) and fixes descriptions

Comment: Now `javafx-jira.kenai.com` is completely down; I tried connecting to the site but after a few minutes, Firefox told me that it had a problem connecting to the site, so I don't even see that notice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use criteria in advanced search:

```
project = JDK AND key = "RT-28874"
```