# Loading fxml too slow in javafx8

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

Hi i am just beginner to javafx. Created one project. And faces problem for slowness for loading javafx. 
So,found its solution from one of stack overflow question (Scene loads too slow - [Scene loads too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328087/scene-loads-too-slow)as) follows:- 
i. Use custom loader as given in ([JavaFX2 - very poor performance when adding custom made (fxml)panels to gridpane dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734885/javafx2-very-poor-performance-when-adding-custom-made-fxmlpanels-to-gridpane)) - Successfully integrated and using
ii. Store controller in HashMap and reuse it with your loader
iii. Use Tom Schindl module (https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2013/08/29/convert-fxml-to-java-as-part-of-the-build/)- for loading fxml. - Don't know how to do it, and as also there are plenty of problem scene as i googled.

Can anybody please provide a way for acomplish **ii** and **iii** task using javafx8. Please it will be great help if any body help me.

Comment: Have you profiled this and figured out what is taking the time? The take-home message from the first link is that the majority of the performance savings can be made externally to the FXML loading.

Comment: James Sir. I am using custom loader as explained there. Performance improved, But i also want to improve in more extend. So need to precompile the fxml to java to increase performance of loading activity. I am using eclipse(Mars.2 (4.5.2) on fedora 15). So want to implement "Tom Schindl module" for javafx8. So please help me regarding it.

Comment: Drastic performance change as done following thing :- i. Optimized CSS file. ii. CSS Minification. iii. Converted .css file to .bss file iv. Used this converted .bss file instead of .css

Comment: That's very interesting. You should consider providing this as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Working Solution :-
Drastic performance change as done following thing :-
 i. Optimized CSS file. ii. CSS Minification. iii. Converted .css file to .bss file iv. Used this converted .bss file instead of .css